# Update Case field from Service Contract related list

Tags: trigger, field-update, after-trigger

I'm asking for your help today because I don't know how to proceed. If you could give me advice or suggestions, I would really appreciate it!

I would like to know how to update Case fields (Company Name and Contact Name ) only when I created a Case on Service Contract record (create Case in the related list of Service Contract). Is it possible to update Case AccountID & Case ContactID automatically upon save from Service Contract record  ?

How is it possible to do that ?
Also Can I update the field of Case record, in relation to a record in a related list  ?
I would like to update the Case field depently of the Task field of my related list.

Thank you in advance for your great help!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through a simple `before insert` or `before update` and inspecting the field `ServiceContractId`

Here is simple code to help you get started

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update) {
  if(trigger.isinsert && trigger.isbefore) {
    CaseTriggerHelper.beforeInsert(trigger.new);
  }

  if(trigger.isupdate && trigger.isbefore) {
    CaseTriggerHelper.beforeUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);
  }
}
```

The Trigger Helper class

```
public with sharing class CaseTriggerHelper {

public static void beforeInsert(List<Case> newCases) {
    List<Case> lstCases = new List<Case>();
    for(Case caseRec: newCases) {
        if(caseRec.ServiceContractId != null) {
            lstCases.add(caseRec);
        }
    }
    populateAccountandContact(lstCases);
    
}

public static void beforeUpdate(List<Case> newCases, Map<Id,Case> oldMap) {
    List<Case> lstCases = new List<Case>();
    for(case caseRec: newCases) {
        if((caseRec.ServiceContractId != oldMap.get(caseRec.Id).ServiceContractId) && (caseRec.ServiceContractId != null)) {
            lstCases.add(caseRec);
        }
    }
     populateAccountandContact(lstCases);
}

public static void populateAccountandContact(List<Case> newCase) {
    Set<Id> serviceContractIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Case caseRec: newCase) {
        serviceContractIds.add(caseRec.ServiceContractId);
    }
    Map<Id,ServiceContract> mapServiceContract = new Map<Id,ServiceContract>([Select Id, AccountId, ContactId FROM ServiceContract WHERE ID IN: serviceContractIds]);
    for(Case caseRec: newCase) {
        caseRec.accountId = mapServiceContract.get(caseRec.ServiceContractId)?.AccountId;
        caseRec.contactId = mapServiceContract.get(caseRec.ServiceContractId)?.ContactId;
    }
  }
}
```